# MySql Update with text or string data

Tags: php, mysql

```
UPDATE user_profiles SET xxx = xxx + 'tt00001' WHERE username = 'challapradyumna';
```

The above query is not acting as it should.

For numeric data xxx is added to the given value but if sting or text is given it is not adding it to the end of existing data.

Comment: What happens? What should happen?

Comment: for numeric data it adds the value provided but for string data it is not adding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your problem '+' cannot con-cat two words. to add(concat) two words you must have to use CONCAT function in the query like:

```
update user_profiles set xxx=CONCAT(xxx,'tt00001') where username='challapradyumna';
```

if you use '+' then it will be considered as mathematical + instead of concat. so, if there are numeric number in xxx then it will mathematically added with xxx.
so, best use is CONCAT in the query.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function instead of '+' operator, e.g. -

```
UPDATE user_profiles SET xxx = CONCAT(xxx, 'tt00001') WHERE username = 'challapradyumna';
```